# iOS App Rejected Because Of Placeholder Icons

Tags: ios, icons, app-store-connect, contentplaceholder

I uploaded my iOS app to the appstore for review and it was rejected due to the following reason as stated in the message I received from Apple via my apps AppStore Connect account.

> **Guideline 2.3.8 - Performance - Accurate Metadata**
>
> *Your app or its metadata does not appear to include final content. Specifically, your app icons appear to be placeholder icons*.

I'm somewhat confused as I went back and checked the app and all icons used are of the actual icon file that was intended for the app and all are the right sizes as well. Is there something Im missing here?

Comment: You will need to resolve this with Apple. We can’t see your icons nor change Apples decisions

Comment: make sure your app icons have all sizes of icons, just for verification create new empty xcode project and assign all icons to it copy/import this to your old project.